# for loop decrement doesn't work

Tags: c++

Hello I am really new into c++ but programed in JS and PHP before.
I want to reverse the string, the only methods I can use are `length()` and `at()`.

I have already an solution but there is something I want to change but c++ is not actually doing what I want actually.

Actual solution:

```
    getline(cin, user_input);
    string inverted_user_input = "";

    int user_input_length = user_input.length() - 1;

    for (int i = user_input_length; i > -1; i--) {
        inverted_user_input += user_input.at(i);
    }

    cout << "The reverse string is: " << inverted_user_input << endl;
```

What I want to do:

```
    getline(cin, user_input);
    string inverted_user_input = "";

    int user_input_length = user_input.length();

    for (int i = user_input_length; i > -1; --i) {
        inverted_user_input += user_input.at(i);
    }

    cout << "The reverse string is: " << inverted_user_input << endl;
```

My first solution work fine but I want to make it looks prettier.
I already know that `length()` begins to count at 1. Thats why I am substract it by 1 on my first code. But I want to use `--i` instead of `i--` to avoid the ugly - 1 like in the first code.

I get a prompt that something exeeds and I checked `i` in first loop but it doesn't decrement. Why?

Comment: _"the only methods I can use are length() and at()"_ Whoops! You're using `+`, too. By my reading of the task, it's likely that you're supposed to be swapping characters in place.

Comment: The difference between `--i` and `i--` doesn't actually matter in a `for` loop's increment. It only matters in somewhere like this `a[i--]` vs. `a[--i]`. The increment is run after the loop regardless of if it's `--i` and `i--`.

Comment: --i means decrease i by 1 and return the result.
i-- means return i, then decrease it by one... I leave you to work out why this makes a difference

Comment: @UKMonkey: Or, more correctly, why it makes no difference at all.

Comment: ok using `i--` or `--i` in a for loop doesn't matter. Then I just leave it how it is actually.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit my point; just getting the OP to think about it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your example `--i` and `i--` do the same thing. You do need to start at length - 1. The difference between `i--` and `--i` is when you're using it in an expression. For example

```
i = 10;
x = i--;
```

results in x = 10, i = 9. However, if you did `--i` instead you'd have x = 9 and i = 9.

Comment: I get it `--i` and `i--` are the same in for loops

Comment: @Selfproblemmade No thats not fully correct. If you had something like `a = b--` it would absolutely be different. Its the fact that you only have one expression there, same as if you had on 2 different lines: `i--; --i;`.

Answer (score 2):

In the `for` loop the post and pre-decrement are not doing what you think. Post and pre-decrement pertain to how the decrement occurs inside a single expression. For example:

```
a = 1;
b = a--; // b = 1;
b = --a; // b = 0;
```

But in the for loop:

```
for (int i = user_input_length; 
    i > -1; 
    --i // This is a single expression
) {
```

So in this case, `--i` and `i--` do the same thing. If you want to clean up that loop, do this:

```
for (int i = user_input.length() - 1; i >= 0; --i) {
    inverted_user_input += user_input.at(i);
}
```

Comment: Same thing, but I get it :=

Answer (score 2):

Here are two ways of reversing a string, one using a [std::reverse](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/reverse) algorithm and the other using a simple user defined function that should be easy to adapt to your needs:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

void reverseString(std::string& s, int length){
    char temp;
    for (int i = 0; i < length / 2; i++)
    {
        temp = s[length - i - 1];
        s[length - i - 1] = s[i];
        s[i] = temp;
    }
}

int main(){
    std::string s = "Hello";
    // Method 1
    std::reverse(s.begin(), s.end());
    std::cout << s;
    // Method 2 using a fn
    reverseString(s, s.length());
    std::cout << s;
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

There are many good answers here on `--i` and `i--` ! But  your code might not work for very long strings.

**Signed or unsigned length ?**

The [length of a string](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/size/) is a `size_t` which is an unsigned type.  It can hold positive values which are larger the largest `int` cant express. 
When you convert such a large length to `int`, you will get a sign overflow: your large positive number will be misinterpreted as being negative.  Your loop would end before the first iteration !

The maximum length of a string is given by [`string::max_size()`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/max_size/).  On some implementations it is smaller than the maximum positive `int`.  But this is not guaranteed by the standard.

**How to solve this issue with `--i` ?**

Working with unsigned requires care: a comparison `i > -1` would be a mixed operation subject to sign overflow as well.  Making it `i>=0` would be equivalent, but it would by definition always be true causing and endless loop. Here an elegant fix that requires `--i` instead of `i--`:

```
string inverted_user_input = "";
for (auto i = user_input.length(); i >0 ; ) {  
    inverted_user_input += user_input.at(--i);
}
```

[**Online demo**](http://ideone.com/4SGEUM) (with in addition display of the key limits)